# Offered a job, no instructions or even confirmation of continuation 8 days later. How to move forward?

Tags: job-offer

8 Days ago I was offered a job at a local grocery supercenter (Definitely a job offer and not an offer for continuing application process).
Phone call from someone at the super center asked me if I was still interested in a job there, asked if my available hours I indicated online were still valid, asked if I was able to do the job, etc etc. Of course I said yes.

The lady on the phone told me to check my email soon and complete two forms I would be getting, within 24 hours or they would expire (and presumably, my hopes of employment with them). She said something about moving onto orientation and in-person training after competing the documents but she didn't specify a timeframe.

As soon as I got off the phone, I filled out the two forms.
One, an html form consenting to a background check. The agency doing the check then sent me confirmation, and sent me update emails on my background checks when they completed over the next 2 days. All came back with a clean bill of health.

The other form, an online fillable pdf through a service called Docusign. It featured spaces for personal details, emergency contacts, agreement to alcohol policy, topped off with a digital signature and date.
I filled it out, presumably clicked finish, and definitely downloaded a copy (but I know downloading a copy does not mean my form was actually submitted or received).

It has now been a week and I have not received any sort of word on training, establishing work schedule, or any kind of online orientation or even a confirmation of receiving my second document.
Maybe this is fine, but from here I should say I am prone to worry. How long should I expect to wait?

Maybe this wait is normal but I am concerned because, upon revist, the link to the second document still allows me to refill the doc. This could suggest the document was never actually submitted, but I hope it's just really poor UX (I don't know what caliber of software Docusign is supposed to be, but I have never been impressed with online form applications in my admittedly short life).
Maybe the sensible thing to do is just to call the center and ask for an update, but seeing as I cannot even remember the name of the woman who offered me the job, I feel it would reflect poorly on me.

Comment: "I cannot even remember the name of the woman" .... Do you record your calls? Many people don't do but if you've recorded, then you may find her name.

Comment: **Maybe the sensible thing to do is just to call the center and ask for an update** - Yes. Do that. **but seeing as I cannot even remember the name of the woman who offered me the job, I feel it would reflect poorly on me** - It won't.

Comment: how would I proceed with this call? Call the center's phone tree and ask for HR (assuming that's an option), or ask for the manager? What if I ask about the status of my job and they say "Oh, I'm sorry, The offer expired because we didn't receive your Forms." How can I explain my situation without making me seem like I neglected my duty to submit my form?

Comment: You say “I did submit my forms, I have a pdf of the DocuSign if it’ll help...”. You have two choices, call them or give up on the job, move, and change your name. Up to you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: I hadn't had a chance to write a thank you comment longer than 15 letters, but now I have the opportunity, so: thank you all for your answers. @gnat I do not think it does, considering that question/answer involves interviews - I have an actual and accepted offer. That answer proposes you do nothing because its just an interview with no promise of receiving updates on that status or your position. I intend to take the advice of joeqwerty et al and call the center tomorrow.

Comment: Alert - THis is a possible scam for Identity theft.  You provided all your PPI information through email to someone you don't know with the reason they needed to set you up in the new company.  You did all the interviews, communication,  etc via online.  They are possible going to provide you with equipment to do on-line training, and ask for a bank deposit slip to deposit money for you to purchase the equipment.  For the background check, they asked for a copy of your drivers license, etc

Comment: I have called the supercenter, was put through to Personnel, and informed the next orientation isn't going to be for at least 2 weeks, at which point the Personnel manager will send out an email setting that up. Person on the phone double checked my application status by checking that my background check came back well. Thankfully, no identity theft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It has now been a week

It's about time(you could wait a few days, up to a week max, but it's a bit of a stretch, but this depends on the location and company mostly) for you to contact the grocery supercenter and see what is going on. Mistakes can happen on their end too!

The longer you wait, the chances are they can get someone else, forget about you, you should remind of yourself from time to time.

> Maybe this wait is normal but I am concerned because, upon revist, the link to the second document still allows me to refill the doc.

This is nothing to worry about, because most of these sites are really bad, trust me, I've dealt with a few myself, all were with bad UX and bugs.

> but seeing as I cannot even remember the name of the woman who offered me the job, I feel it would reflect poorly on me.

Knowing a name or not, you should definitely get in touch, we're all humans and forgetting a name should not stop you for getting the job.